# Reusable FlatList Component React Native problems with item

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a reusable component of a flatlist that can be used on different screens, with different functions. However, on one specific screen, I encounter a problem regarding passing the flatlist's renderItem's id to navigation props.

Reusable flatlist:

```
            const ReusableFlatList = (props) => (
            <FlatList
            data={props.data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (

                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={props.onNavigate} >
                    
                
                    <View>
                        <Image 
                            source={{uri: item.image}}
                        
                        />
                    </View>
                <View >
                        <Text >{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                
            )}

            />
        )
```

and using it on a screen:

```
    <ReusableFlatList data={dataArray} onNavigate={() => props.navigation.navigate('Screen', {id: item.id})/>
```

And getting error that item is undefined.

Comment: will have to pass the item from `ReusableFlatList` component as function parameter.

Comment: How would that be done?

Comment: hi, I think it would be more helpful if you can share the code for the screen where the error happened. From what I see, the problem is exactly what the error said, item is undefined hence it will trigger an error because you tried to access `id` of an undefined.

Comment: @garjted yes, that's the problem. My question was, how do I get the item from ReusableFlatList to the screen where I need to access it?

Comment: @flaneurx oh ok, I get what you're trying to do. I'll write it in the answer. give me a min

Comment: @flaneurx check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass the item from ReusableFlatList component as function parameter.

on `ReusableFlatList` component,

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={()=> props.onNavigate(item)} //passing item as parameter
>
```

and in the other component receive the item as a parameter to `onNavigate` function,

```js
<ReusableFlatList 
  data={dataArray} 
  onNavigate={ (item) => props.navigation.navigate('Screen', {id: item.id}) //receiving item as parameter
/>
```

Comment: Great. Happy coding!